# Basic Ajax in Symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I am new to symfony. Currently, I am importing a JS file into a Twig template. In this JS file I have a very basic ajax call **which fails to link to the php file**. I was wondering if someone can advise how to properly link to the .php file in Symfony 2?

Many thanks in advance!

I am unable to use `{{ asset() }}` because I am not in a `.twig` file.

Twig Tempalte

```
{% block jquery %} 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/foo/js/searchjs.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

My JavaScript `searchjs.js`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myfile.php?search=toys",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
       alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do people keep tagging Symfony questions with both [tag:symfony1] **and** [tag:symfony2] lately?

Comment: You haven't explained your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the URL you're trying to acces should be a controller url. For example :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/my/controller/action/",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
       alert(data);
    }
});
```

I guess that even if you're new to SF2, you've already understood how controller work. Then you just have to create a controller + a route that uses the `/my/controller/action/` one.

If what you want to do is using a json response, it's quite simple : in this controller action, just return a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse` with as content your json encoded data.

And that should work fine :)

Edit : you can see more about it [here in the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response)